# Numbering order of Dates for Dimension in other Column

Tags: date, dax

I'm relatively new to DAX and I believe there should be straight forward solution for this problem.

I have ID for customers and corresponding periods, for which we have orders for them.
These are not in particular order, so I need to add a column in which, for each ID, it shows me what is the first, second, third ..etc period with the customer.

see below the in the third column, what I would expect.
[image]

since I'm new, I have not tried anything worth mentioning here, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this **calculated column**

```
Rank = 
VAR ThisID = 'Table1'[ID]
RETURN
    RANKX(
        FILTER(
            'Table1',
            'Table1'[ID] = ThisID
        ),
        'Table1'[start Date],
        ,
        ASC,
        DENSE
    )
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick questions, worked fine !!